# Some IBindableComponent interface implementation issues

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to implement the IBindableComponent to the the following code:

```
Public Class InfragisticsToolStripBindableButton
  Inherits Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ButtonTool
  Implements IBindableComponent

  Private _DataBindings As ControlBindingsCollection
  Private _BindingContext As BindingContext

  Public Event Disposed As EventHandler Implements IBindableComponent.Disposed

  Sub New()
    MyBase.New(String.Empty)
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property DataBindings() As ControlBindingsCollection
    Get
      If _DataBindings Is Nothing Then
        _DataBindings = New ControlBindingsCollection(Me)
      End If
      Return _DataBindings
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Property BindingContext() As BindingContext
    Get
      If _BindingContext Is Nothing Then
        _BindingContext = New BindingContext()
      End If
      Return _BindingContext
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As BindingContext)
      _BindingContext = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Overloads Sub Dispose()
    '???????? include bellow code '
    RaiseEvent Disposed(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
  End Sub

  'Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
  '  If disposing Then
  '    If _DataBindings IsNot Nothing Then
  '      _DataBindings.Clear()
  '      _DataBindings = Nothing
  '    End If
  '    _BindingContext = Nothing
  '  End If
  '  MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
  'End Sub
End Class
```

**1 problem:**
Warning: event 'Disposed' conflicts with property 'Disposed' in the base class 'DisposableObject' and should be declared 'Shadows'

**2 problem:**
Error:
Class 'InfragisticsToolStripBindableButton' must implement 'Property Site As ISite' for interface 'System.ComponentModel.IComponent'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.

Why should I implement "IComponent" if I implement "IBindableComponent"??

**3 problem:**
How should I override "Dispose", if it's already implemented in the base class, but is not virtual apparently.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to name `Disposed` any name, it does not need the same as the interface.

```
 Public Event StripDisposed As EventHandler Implements IBindableComponent.Disposed
```

see how it remains implemnts IBindableComponent.Disposed.